# Deserialize JSON fields that may have different types

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using gson to deserialize a json file to an object. Various parts of the json have a "properties" array, and every property is itself an array containing up to 6 optional fields that will always be one type, with a 7th field, "default", that may contain a boolean, string, or an int. My object class looks like this

```
public class Object {
  private string name;
  private Map<String, Property> properties;
  //Code
  }
    class Property {
      private String type;
      ...
      @SerializedName("default")
      private default_field;
      //...
    }
  }
```

I see my options as creating either creating 3 types of of `Property`, each differing only in what type `default_field` is, or always taking it as a string and dealing with converting it to the proper type when I need to actually use the value for something. Option 2 might give me issues if some values of `default_field' contain numbers as strings and others contain numbers as int. When I eventually pass these values along, I won't be able to tell what type they originated as.

Is there someway to be vague when taking in the value of this field, while still knowing the expected data type?

Comment: why not use `private Object default_field` ? Then use `instanceOf` to get real type?

Comment: When gson attempts to deserialize the json, any instance of default_field results in an error. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BOOLEAN`. gson seems to expect actual variable types to be declared.